# getElementById won't work in VBA, error 438

Tags: excel, vba, getelementbyid

I am relatively new at VBA (I know the basics, but not much else) and I am trying to get some code set up that will fill out online forms for me, but when I run my code I get a 438 error:

> object doesnt support this property or method

when it gets to

```
ie.document.getElementById ("q")
```

I have added the HTML object library and Microsoft internet controls to my references. I have looked at tons of online forums. I have even copied and pasted an entire script directly into VBA. Nothing will make it use `getElementById()`. Here is my code:

```
Sub internetstuff()

Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate ("https://www.google.com/")

Set searchbx = ie.document.getElementById("q")

searchbx.Value = "Howdy!"

End Sub
```

What should happen is that it should open InternetExplorer, go to Google, and populate the search bar with "Howdy!".
Instead, It only opens google, then I get the error message and it stops running.

Comment: Are you sure google.com has a `q` ID? I did a quick search and didn't see one...However, the searchbox has `name="q"`, so you may want to use `getElementsByTagName="q"` and use `searchbx[0].Value = "howdy"`...Perhaps this is helping you learn, but you could always just do `ie.navigate ("https://www.google.com/search?q=Howdy!")`, no?

Comment: In the HTML elements it says: name="q" and I watched a youtube video where this was used and it worked. Also, I have tried it with other websites and different IDs and can't get it to work. Could it be a setting I have set?

Comment: Are you use using `getElementByID` worked for a `Name`?

Answer (score 2):

Because `"q"` is not an `ID`, it's a `Name`.

You have to use `GetElementsByName` and select the 1st Element

try this:

```
Sub internetstuff()

Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

ie.Visible = True

ie.Navigate ("https://www.google.com/")

    Do Until ie.ReadyState >= 4
        DoEvents
    Loop


Set searchbx = ie.document.getElementsByName("q")(0)

searchbx.Value = "Howdy!"

End Sub
```

I have also added a waiting Event, in case it takes time to load Google.

---

## Result:

[image]

Comment: This still yielded an error on the line Set searchbx = ie.document.getElementsByName("q")(0)

Comment: I wonder if there is something in my computer settings that is preventing me from getting it to do what i want

Comment: You sure you changed it to Element**s** .. It's working fine in my system.

Comment: runtime 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: That is why I am so confused, @mikku, I have literally copied and pasted others code and it still wont work on my computer

Comment: You have not defined `searchbx` as Anything, Right ?

Comment: no, @mikku I have not. I just defined it as an object and ran it and it still gave me the error.

Comment: @Matt.C .... Not sure then ... I could only see that you were using the wrong method . Which is corrected by `getElementsByName` .

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the help @mikku

Answer (score 0):

A more concise and efficient way is to use querySelector to return first match for the name attribute

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub internetstuff()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.google.com/"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.querySelector("[name=q]").Value = "Howdy"
         Stop '<delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: same error when it got to the queryselector line. Your code makes sense and I know that it should work, but I think there must be something in my computer system/settings that is preventing it from working. I appreciate the help though, @QHarr

Comment: yes, I tried redoing some similar code on my desktop and it worked. I am not sure why. @Qharr

Comment: Try ie.document.parentWindow.execscript "document.querySelector('[name=q]').Value = 'Howdy';"

Comment: Hi, @QHarr, I have been trying some different things and the problem is definitely my computer. I made some code on my desktop that worked (it was a simple bot to fill out some online forms) and I sent it to my laptop, and it did not work there. Thanks for all your help, sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: Not at all. These things happen. Sometimes using internetexplorermedium and ensuring website is on whitelist of urls.

Comment: Ive finally found the issue! Getelementbyid is actually missing from my reference library on vba internetexplorer. I have no idea why, nor do I have any clue on how to fix it.

Comment: and same issue for querySelector? Microsoft HTML Object Library reference should  be in all Microsoft Excel installs (at least all since Microsoft [paid a ton of money](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777868/6241235) to make that happen!)_

Comment: yeah, same problem, and I can't  figure out why. I think it may be a problem with getting it through my university, but its not too big of a deal. At my internship I use my desktop, and at school we have access to computer labs should I need it. I appreciate all of your help though @QHarr

Comment: No worries. Happy to help.